# convert a column type 'object' to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I have a column of numbers (type 'object') in my df:

1

2,23

5,23

200

I tried to convert using astype, but an error tells me that they cannot convert with commas,
so I tried using

```
df[column].str.replace(',','.', inplace=True)
```

but the results tranformed all values without comma into NaNs..

So I tried another solution:

```
mask=df[column].str.contains(',',na=false) 
df.loc[mask].str.replace(',','.',inplace=True)
```

But an error message tells me that a dataframe has no str function,
what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and `df[column] = df[column].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for share:

```
mask=df[column].str.contains(',',na=False)
df[column]=df[column].mask(mask,df[column].str.replace(',','.'))
```